# Il mismatch between 'P1' version '20080116' and 'P2' version '20070207'

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am building MFC application which uses other c++ library.I am using vs 2008 and compiled all the library project in vs 2008.

It is compiling well in debug mode but failed to run in Debug Unicode mode,Release,Release Unicode mode.

I found in the net that VS 2008SP1 is required to be installed but how come it is compiling in debug mode.

Please suggest how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If compiling a solution with multiple projects you should compile all projects with the same compiler (version) to be sure it works.

I once got the same error message like you. If I remember correctly the problem occured because *link time code generation* was used. My solution was to *rebuild all*, another solution might have been disabling *link time code generation*.

Answer (score 11):

In Microsoft terminology, P1 is the parser (front-end), and P2 is the code generator (back-end). With link-time code generation (LTGC) enabled, the result of P1 is stored in a file and P2 is performed later at link time.

If you *downgraded* your compiler, you should do a full rebuild, otherwise the link step will try to use the incompatible P1 output, which will trigger that error.

If you *upgraded* the compiler, Visual Studio automatically does a full rebuild, so this should never happen (if it does anyway, just perform a full rebuild).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (Installer) which resolved the problem. Service Pack can be downloaded from following link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=10986

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem just with other numbers as well using Visual studio 2015. 
The problem was in one of the libraries that I linked to my project was build using VS2015 Update 3. The solution that worked for me - update Visual Studio to 2015 Update 3.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same problem. For reference, this was the error message: `LINK : fatal error C1900: Il mismatch between 'P1' version '20150812' and 'P2' version '20130802'`