# C++ Il mismatch between 'P1' version '20100826' and 'P2' version '20080116'

Tags: c++

I have solution that consist of 100 projects. And one of them during build throwing exception. All projects using the same toolset.

> Error 815 error C1900: Il mismatch between 'P1' version '20100826' and
>   'P2' version '20080116'
>
> Error 816 error LNK1257: code generation failed

This project is Dynamic library, with such configuration options.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I read that it might be because LTCG is enabled but in my situation LTCG is disabled.

How to fix this problem? What to do?

Build problem in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959973/il-mismatch-between-p1-version-20080116-and-p2-version-20070207

Comment: Looks like you are trying to link some code with with VS 2010 into a project built with VS 2008? Check the toolset setting for all your projects is the same (its probably best to change them all to vs2013)

Comment: It seems like it has nothing to do with your projects, but the compiler itself. The [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks07be9f.aspx) suggests to update and repair your MSVC installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Il mismatch between 'P1' version '20080116' and 'P2' version '20070207'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959973/il-mismatch-between-p1-version-20080116-and-p2-version-20070207)